# Resizing image with picasso

Tags: android, image, picasso

Hey everyone I have been running into an issue with Picasso. I am trying to load an image from sound cloud but it keeps appearing stretched or very small. Here is my XML

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/album_cover_art"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment_content_item_top_margin"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_image_placeholder"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

I tried to use picasso's resize and center inside but the image appears small.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(mSelectedTrack.getArtworkURL()).resize(800,300).centerInside().into(mAlbumCoverArt);
```

Using picasso's resize and center crop maintains the image view size but leads to the image appearing stretched.

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(mSelectedTrack.getArtworkURL()).resize(800,300).centerCrop().into(mAlbumCoverArt);
```

Any ideas on a way to do this that is easier than writing a function to resize it myself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

for your imageview:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@id/img"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"  //add this
android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

And in `picasso` use `.fit().centerCrop()`

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(mSelectedTrack.getArtworkURL()).resize(800,300).fit().centerCrop().into(mAlbumCoverArt);
```

Comment: I am getting a crash with this solution, stack trace is saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fit cannot be used with resize.

Comment: try deleting your resize..you are already adding width height to xml

Answer (score 7):

I avoided image stretching using :

```
.resize(800,0)
```

Passing `0` as second parameter it preserved the image proportions.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try setting height or width to fixed and other to wrap content and load Picasso with .fitXY and don't use . resize.

Answer (score -4):

Give a try to Glide.
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .centerCrop()
            .override(300, 300)
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: The question is about picasso not glide.